# How many times is the list of objects retrieved in a C# foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach

I typically try to store the array/collection as a local variable before running a foreach loop: as opposed to calling the Get function inside of foreach. This is because I assume that it will have to fetch that array on each iteration of the loop, and I would rather it only have to get the array/collection one time. I'm having trouble finding documentation to support my theory, so I wanted to ask the gurus.

```
//Assume that FindStringsContaining() is a CPU
//intensive operation. Does it run only once?
foreach(string data in FindStringsContaining("Data"))
{
    //use the data
}
```

Comment: It is only called once

Comment: You could have [easily tested this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kyDhgC)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel that is a neat little program. The thought didn't occur to me because I don't have the source code of the called function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will always run exactly **once**.

Foreach operates on an `IEnumerable`, and simply iterates over the collection; executing the code inside the loop for each item it finds.

Note that modifying the collection during enumeration (which would potentially require a re-enumeration) is explicitly not allowed (an `InvalidOperationException` will be thrown).

Comment: One of my primary concerns was that the collection might be modified if there was a get happening each time. Knowing about this Exception really helps me understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

The method call would only happen once. It then returns an `IEnumerable<string>` which is iterating over in a streaming fashion (calling the `MoveNext` method while items remain in the collection or a break isn't hit).

Answer (score 1):

It is called once. A quick way to verify this is to place a breakpoint inside your FindStringsContaining() method, and you can see it is only hit once.